# How to customise Date format in toISOString()

Tags: javascript

How to use toISOString to get DD MMM YYY HH:MM.
I tried this way..

`<%= locals.user.stats.dateLastLogin.toISOString().replace("T"," ").replace("Z","") %>`

output:
2016-12-13 08:08:22.929

requird output: 12 DEC 2016 08:08pm

Comment: iso format is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.nnnZ` - replacing the T and Z isn't exactly trying to get the date format you want, is it

Comment: Related: [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Native date handling in js is quite terrible, if you have the option, look into using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), then you could just do `moment(locals.user.stats.dateLastLogin).format('DD MMM YYYY hh:MM:A')`